Who is DKBLU on Shirley Bassey's 'Thank You For The Years' album?
On Shirley Bassey's Thank You For The Years album, three songs are written by DKBLU. Who is this person or whose writing alias is this?
I've asked ChatGPT and Microsoft Co-Pilot, and they gave different answers: ChatGPT suggested it's Jim Steinbeck, but I can't find any evidence to back this up, like references on other releases.

source

I am tempted to downvote for the assumption that ChatGPT or Microsoft Pilot would be able to provide meaningful answers to uncommon questions.

Searching Google for "Shirley Bassey DKBLU", I did stumble upon this page on The D-Word, "the worldwide community of documentary professionals". At first I didn't think too much of it, as it is clearly mentioned to be the nickname of the person whose profile that page represents, Dana Kaproff, but it does mention there and on his personal website that he has cooperated with her. Respectively:

Other album credits demonstrate his diversity, ranging from rocker Pat Benatar, to adult contemporary icon Dame Shirley Bassey [..]


Other album credits reflect his range and diversity, including Grammy winners Pat Benatar and Shirley Bassey [..]

Kaproff is an award-winning songwriter, among other things. His initials, DK, are featured prominently on his website.
This page on PBS.org mentions how "as a songwriter, [Kaproff] wrote half of the new material on the latest Shirley Bassey album, "Thank You For The Years"".
Finally, note how on Discog's Thank You For The Years release page his name isn't mentioned otherwise.
I think it can be concluded this is the name you're looking for :)

Fantastic research thank you. I'll amend the MusicBrainz entries to glue together this mystery.

https://musicbrainz.org/release/3205728c-624d-426b-80c2-6e01897a5652
